# WebRTC video streaming doesn't work through http

Tags: javascript, webrtc, peerjs

I'm trying to create game with WebRTC (Peer.js). And I can't make video calls through "http"... Maybe It works only through https?
P.S. All working (that I saw) examples for media calls use https!

```
1) http://cdn.peerjs.com/demo/videochat/ (doesn't work)
2) https://simplewebrtc.com/demo.html (works)
```

Comment: WebRTC can only be used in secure origin only. It is a policy of Google. That's why http can't work

Comment: Ok! But DataConnection works fine through "http"!... Thanks!

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy That's inaccurate.  WebRTC is fine with HTTP.  The issue comes with media device capture.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not webrtc but the getusermedia API is supported only over secure origins (https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins).

So you can use localhost for testing on your machine but for deployment, you will need https.

Comment: To be clear, only the Google Chrome browser imposes this limitation at the moment.