# WEBRTC oneway stream via HTTP without getusermedia

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, webrtc

We are working on a JS frontend to display a video stream with low latency and thus we are using WebRTC.

we read in this article that HTTPS is required since getUserMedia is a *powerfull function*. [Link to Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41922515/webrtc-video-streaming-doesnt-work-through-http)
It is only one-way, do we do not try to access getusermedia. Still when using Chrome or any mobile browser, the  official webrtc test sites work fine but our setup is only accessible on MacOS with Safari.

Could someone with WebRTC knowledge tell me:

**Is it correct to say that displaying an incoming WebRTC video stream should be possible to display on firefox or chrome via a HTTP and when there is no attempt to access the users Camera or Microphone via getusermedia**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a [discussion](https://github.com/w3c/webrtc-pc/issues/1945#issuecomment-420510604) about this on w3c page. Looks like there's no requirement for secure context for webrtc aside from getUserMedia.

Also I just tested an incoming-only webrtc video stream served on remote machine in firefox 101.0.1 and chromium 105.0.5141.0, works fine without https.

The same setup but with getUserMedia doesn't work.

So I guess your statement is correct.

Comment: Hi Ivan, Thanks for confirming. Is this a private code you used for testing the incoming stream or is this something that i can also use to check?

Comment: It's an installation of janus with streaming plugin in a private network. The code is public, here is a demo page: https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/streamingtest.html

Comment: Thanks. But JANUS is a HTTPS page. I guess you set up the public code on your machine for testing it with HTTP, right?

Comment: Yes, I already had an installation of Janus accessible via http